# Django: filtering by value or returning all records

Tags: python, django, filter

I have the following piece of code (django, python):

```
def function(self, some_id):
    if some_id:
        return Model1.objects.filter(model2__id=some_id)
    else:
        return Model1.objects.all()
```

I'm wondering it is possible to refactoring this code with a single return statement? Model1 has a foreign key on Model2.id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def function(self, some_id):
    filter_kwargs = {}

    if some_id:
        filter_kwargs['model2__id'] = some_id

    return Model1.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs)
```

Should satisfy your question, though I'd say that its most likely okay as written.

Comment: This is a very simple and clear solution. Thank you!
The original solution is also good, but not in the case of several if.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can fix this like:

```
def function(self, some_id):
    return Model1.objects.filter(*(some_id and [Q(model2__id=some_id)] or []))
```

But this is rather cryptical.

Personally I like to implement a `filter_not_none`, that simply filters away statements with a `None` as value, like:

```
def filter_not_none(qs, **kwargs):
    return qs.filter(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.item() if v is not None})
```

Then we can simply use:

```
def function(self, some_id):
    return filter_not_none(Model1.objects, model2__id=some_id)
```

This works with an arbitrary number of *named* parameters. So not positional parameters, or `Q` objects.

This works since a `filter(..)` with no parameters, does not filter anything. We use dictionary comprehension, to thus check which `kwargs` have a not-`None` value, and we only pass these to the `.filter(..)` call.

You can then for example use:

```
return filter_not_none(
    Model.objects,
    name=some_name,
    date__lt=some_date
)
```

in case `some_name` is `None`, we do not filter on the name, in case `some_date` is `None` we do not filter on the `date__lt`, in case both are `None`, we do not filter at all, and in case both are *not* `None`, we filter on both.

We can extend it to get it work with `Q` objects as well (as `*args`), but inspecting these `Q`-objects, and expressions, would be quite hard to do, and furthermore could result in all kinds of unwanted behavior. But an extension that takes `Q` objects as well is:

```
def filter_not_none(qs, *args, **kwargs):
    # warning, does not perform manipulations on Q-objects, Q-expressions
    # and unnamed parameters in general
    return qs.filter(
        *args,
        **{k: v for k, v in kwargs.item() if v is not None}
    )
```